# java week count for previous month

Tags: java, calendar

In java how can one get number of weeks of previous month, week starting from Monday

```
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

`cal` is `Calendar` instance

It returns 0 if first day of week is other than Monday. So it has to be counted as previous months last week, that's my requirement.

Comment: How to count the weeks which start one month and ends the next month?

Comment: I think a few examples might make your question more clear.

Comment: so you want the number of complete weeks (i.e. Monday-Sunday) which are completely included in last month? If we look at October 2012, this would be 4, for November it would be 3 right?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but probably you're looking for something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date()); // today's date
// previous month from today
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
// get to the 1st week
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7 * (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)/7));
// Get to the 1st Mon of last month
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
// # of days in last month
int maxDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
// print # of week since Mon of last month
int numWeeks = ((maxDay-cal.get(Calendar.DATE))/7)+1;
System.out.printf("# of weeks from Mon in last month: %d%n", numWeeks);
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, it returns 4 for October, but October has 5 weeks starting from monday

Comment: check the edit now. It wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted 4 or 5 for Oct 2012.

Comment: number of weeks in the previous month starting from Monday, Current Month is November for October is previous month and there are 5 weeks starting from Monday in October +1 is not the solution as it will not work in majority of the cases

Comment: `it will not work in majority of the cases`: Can you tell me a specific example when this code will not work?

Comment: set the current date to 2 feb, 2013 and see the out

Comment: In Feb 2013 there are 4 Mondays i.e. 4, 11, 18 & 25 and above code will also give you 4 as output.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty (given the requirements as asked in my comment above):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
    while ( cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY ) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    }
    int startingMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int numberOfWeeks = 0;

    while (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == startingMonth ) {          
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);            
        numberOfWeeks++;                        
    }
    System.out.println("weeks in last month:" + numberOfWeeks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Korgen, but it return 4 for last month, where as October has 5 weeks starting from Monday

Comment: check my change... this will give you the number of weeks started last month (i.e. number Mondays in last month). First thought was that you only want to count full weeks, but apparently you also want weeks which only were started?!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all the Mondays in the previous month here you are:

```
public int getNofWeeks() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
    while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
        cal.roll(Calendar.DATE, false);
    }        
    int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int previousMonth = (currentMonth + 12 - 1) % 12;
    int prePreviousMonth = (currentMonth + 12 - 2) % 12;
    int nofWeeks = 0;        
    do {
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        if (month == previousMonth) {
            nofWeeks++;
        }
        if (month == prePreviousMonth) {
            break;
        }
        cal.roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, false);            
    } while (true);        
    return nofWeeks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

If your `Calendar` is actually a `GregorianCalendar` then convert to a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) myCal;
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime();
```

Extract the date-only.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

### 1st to 1st

Get first of this month, and first of next month. Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) (note the plural).

```
LocalDate firstOfThisMonth = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth() );
    LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth() );
```

Calculate weeks between.

```
long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( firstOfThisMonth , firstOfNextMonth );
```

### Monday-to-Monday

If you want Monday-to-Monday, used different [`TemporalAdjuster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) already defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) with a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object.

```
LocalDate firstMondayOfThisMonth = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
LocalDate firstMondayOfNextMonth = ld.plusMonths( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );

long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( firstMondayOfThisMonth , firstMondayOfNextMonth );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).